# Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on Sign in link on site alibaba.com

This is my test case:

```
public class TestCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String URL = "http://www.alibaba.com/";
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(URL);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        SignIn.SignIn_click(driver).click();
    }

}
```

This is object class where in am locating the web element

```
package PageObjects;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class SignIn {


    private static WebElement element = null;

    public static WebElement SignIn_click(WebDriver driver) {
        element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions
                .visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                        .xpath("//a[@data-val='ma_signin']")));
        element = driver.findElement(By
                .xpath("//a[@data-val='ma_signin']"));
        return element;

    }

}
```

But when I run this code , I'm always getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //a[@data-val='ma_signin'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
    Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '86a5d70', time: '2017-02-16 07:47:51 -0800'
    System info: host: 'ANUM-PC', ip: '172.16.11.162', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41), userDataDir=C:\Users\Anum\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir1716_14873}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=59.0.3071.115, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
    Session ID: d0c1083c113270bd4ded08846544878e
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:257)
        at PageObjects.SignIn.SignIn_click(SignIn.java:15)
        at AutomationFramework.TestCase.main(TestCase.java:24)
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: try increasing timeout. make it 100 seconds and see what happens.

Comment: Getting this now:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //a[@data-val='ma_signin'] (tried for 100 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: This usually happens when you have a *loadng* overlay placed while page is loading. In such cases selenium cannot find elements after *loading* disappears. Do you have any such overlay in place?

Comment: Yes , an overlay also opens when user mouse hover on SIgn in link. But clicking on sign in will redirect the user to sign in page.

So what to do in this case?

Comment: wait for the invisibility of the overlay :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this following:

```
package PageObjects;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class SignIn {

    private static WebElement element = null;
    public static WebElement SignIn_click(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {
    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('J_SC_header')/header/div[2]//span[1]/a[@data-val='ma_signin']"));

    while (!isDisplayed(element)) 
    {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println("Element is not visible yet");
    }
    return element;

    }
    public static boolean isDisplayed(WebElement element) {
        try {
            if(element.isDisplayed())
                return element.isDisplayed();
            }catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

The `xpath` you have constructed `//a[@data-val='ma_signin']` is not unique. The `xpath` matches with 3 nodes. If you want to click on **`Sign In`** button you can consider using this unique `xpath`:

```
//div[@id='J_SC_header']//div[@class='sc-hd-row sc-hd-main']//a[@rel='nofollow'][@data-val='ma_signin']
```

Comment: I always get issues regarding element not found or element not present and this is most likely due to xpath issues. How can i get expert in finding the xpath? Though i am using the same xpath in firepath while inspecting the element in firebug and element is getting inspect.

Comment: @user3030202 Good Question :) `xpath` provided by `firepath` is `absolute xpath` and is your reference to construct a unique `logical xpath`. Thanks

Comment: E.g. i am now on this form 

https://login.alibaba.com/?spm=a2700.8293689.0.0.NdeZUw&tracelog=hd_signin


and trying to access the Email field to enter email using this xpath , but again getting element not found.


xpath(".//*[@id='fm-login-id']")

also tried this as well but no luck

xpath("//input[@name='loginId']")

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void waitVisibilityOfElementLocated(WebDriver driver, String locator) {
        String key = "";
        WebElement element = null;
        try {
            key = Utility.fetchLocatorKey(locator);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in getText method, " + e.getMessage());
        }

        if (key.endsWith("id")) {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
            element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(locator)));
        } else if (key.endsWith("cssselector")) {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
            element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(locator)));
        } else if (key.endsWith("linktext")) {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
            element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText(locator)));
        } else if (key.endsWith("xpath")) {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
            element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(locator)));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I lived same issue in my local, and then I realized made screen size 125% in display settings. After changed to 100% the element could be located.
"TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of [[RemoteWebDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (8ec6c...)] -> xpath: //span[@class = 'v-button ...] (tried for 30 second(s) with 1000 milliseconds interval)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, this is not how selenium works I believe. Zoom has nothing to do with the dom structure.